# how to extract the data from image using python

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, ocr, python-tesseract

Hi I am a newbie to ocr models, I have 2000 Receipt jpeg images, I am  trying to extract the  data from an image, it shows some error, Please how to do.
It tried this :

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('E:/Receipts/Receipts/*.jpeg'): 
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

text=pytesseract.image_to_string(image_list,lang = 'eng')

print(text)
```

### Error it showing :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-fb43962ff6d0> in <module>()
      6     image_list.append(im)
      7 
----> 8 text=pytesseract.image_to_string(image_list,lang = 'eng')
      9 
     10 print(text)





~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_and_get_output(image, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout, return_bytes)
    240     temp_name, input_filename = '', ''
    241     try:
--> 242         temp_name, input_filename = save_image(image)
    243         kwargs = {
    244             'input_filename': input_filename,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in save_image(image)
    169         return temp_name, realpath(normpath(normcase(image)))
    170 
--> 171     image, extension = prepare(image)
    172     input_file_name = temp_name + os.extsep + extension
    173     image.save(input_file_name, format=extension, **image.info)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in prepare(image)
    143 
    144     if not isinstance(image, Image.Image):
--> 145         raise TypeError('Unsupported image object')
    146 
    147     extension = 'PNG' if not image.format else image.format

TypeError: Unsupported image object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the stacktrace, you see that pytesseract complains about the data type you are feeding it with.

Indeed with your call
`text=pytesseract.image_to_string(image_list,lang = 'eng')`
you are trying to feed `pytesseract.image_to_string` with a list of images, which is not possible.

If you want to get a list of texts, one for each image, iterate on the images:

```py
texts = [pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang = 'eng') for img in image_list]
for text in texts:
    print(text)
```

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745519/use-pytesseract-to-recognize-text-from-image).

Comment: not only that, the image format should be PNG and not JPEG