# How to get rid of image noise for improving results with PyTesseract?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, text, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to get the text "P1" and "P2" from the upper left corner of the video.

[P1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0XpR.jpg)

[P2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeptK.jpg)

I take a frame and crop them down to following images and then apply the image processing found here:

[P1 Crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcY2Q.png)

[P2 Crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K90ls.png)

[use pytesseract to recognize text from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745519/use-pytesseract-to-recognize-text-from-image)

and while it works on cropped still images I edited manually using an image editor, it doesn't work when taking frames from the video using cv2.

I'm not sure why this is but I suspect it has something to do with the black and white background like in the picture below, but I don't know how to get rid of it without also removing the text.

[P1 post image manipulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zb2j.png)

and here's my code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import re
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def determineWinner(video):
    winnerRect = [(70,95),(146,152)]
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    if(cap.isOpened() == False):
        print("No dice")
        return
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    print(fps)
    print(frames)
    desiredSeek = frames - int(fps * 9)
    print(desiredSeek)
    seconds = desiredSeek/fps
    print(seconds)
    minutes = seconds/60
    print(minutes)
    partial = minutes - int(minutes)
    print(partial)
    seconds = partial * 60
    print(seconds)
    print(str(int(minutes)) +":"+ str(seconds))

    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,(desiredSeek))

    ret,img = cap.read()
    winTxt = []
    p1Count = 0
    p2Count = 0

    cv2.namedWindow("",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    ret,img = cap.read()
    while ret:
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
        if key == ord('e'):
            ret,img = cap.read()
            if ret:
                winROI = img[winnerRect[0][1]:winnerRect[1][1],winnerRect[0][0]:winnerRect[1][0]]
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(winROI, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
                thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

                # Morph open to remove noise and invert image
                kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
                opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
                invert = 255-opening
                invert=cv2.resize(invert,None,fx=2,fy=2)
                wConfig='-l eng --oem 1 --psm 10 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=P12'
                winTxt = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert,config=wConfig)
                cv2.rectangle(img,winnerRect[0],winnerRect[1],(255,0,0),2)
                cv2.imshow("winroi",invert)
                cv2.imshow("",img)
                cv2.resizeWindow("",800,600)
                print(winTxt)
                desiredSeek+=1
                seconds = desiredSeek/fps
                minutes = seconds/60
                partial = minutes - int(minutes)
                seconds = partial * 60
                print(str(int(minutes)) +":"+ str(seconds))
            else:
                break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You could try to apply a color filter (one for the blue inside the P1) and one for the pink inside the P2. Then, you would only see that specific color. You could then apply the other functions. Let me know if you know what I mean.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu So filter our the non red/blue colors, is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works as a testing script. I only extracted the parameters for the image containing `P1`. For applying a filter on a new image, just erase the predefined thresholds values as following:

### From:

`low_blue, low_green, low_red, upper_blue, upper_green, upper_red = (115, 0, 0, 255, 178, 255)`

### To:

`low_blue, low_green, low_red, upper_blue, upper_green, upper_red = (0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255)`

And start modifying the parameters as described below. After determining the parameters, press `esc` to exit the program, take the parameters shown in the console and paste them in the thresholds tuple.

---

***How to use it:***

- Very important. For this to work properly, you have to select with left click of the mouse, the window from `cv2.imshow()` , in this case `Original image` or `Binary image`
- `q` increases and `w` decreases the lower blue threshold
- `a` increases and `s` decreases the lower green threshold
- ... so on and so forth for both lower and upper colors (`BGR`) thresholds

---

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

low_blue, low_green, low_red, upper_blue, upper_green, upper_red = (115, 0, 0, 255, 178, 255)

# Get picture
path = "C:\\Users\\asd\\asd\\P1.png"
frame = cv2.imread(path)

while 1:

    lower_color = np.array((low_blue, low_green, low_red))
    upper_color = np.array((upper_blue, upper_green, upper_red))

    # extract binary image with active blue regions
    binary_image = cv2.inRange(frame, lower_color, upper_color)

    cv2.imshow('Original image', binary_image)

    #erode for the little white contour to dissapear
    binary_image = cv2.erode(binary_image, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(3,3)))
    binary_image = cv2.dilate(binary_image, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(3,3)))

    cv2.imshow('Binary image  ', binary_image)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    if k == ord('q'):
        low_blue += 1
    if k == ord('w'):
        low_blue -= 1
    if k == ord('a'):
        low_green += 1
    if k == ord('s'):
        low_green -= 1
    if k == ord('z'):
        low_red += 1
    if k == ord('x'):
        low_red -= 1
    if k == ord('e'):
        upper_blue += 1
    if k == ord('r'):
        upper_blue -= 1
    if k == ord('d'):
        upper_green += 1
    if k == ord('f'):
        upper_green -= 1
    if k == ord('c'):
        upper_red += 1
    if k == ord('v'):
        upper_red -= 1

    print("low_blue=", low_blue, "low_green=", low_green, "low_red=",low_red, "upper_blue", upper_blue, "upper_green=",
          upper_green, "upper_red=",upper_red)


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

## The results

**From**:

[image]

**To:**

[image]

Comment: Give me a moment I'm testing to see if it improve recognition

Comment: It works very well. I'm getting a way more correct reads than before. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to play with the values and check for better results if you need. Have a nice day :)