# enhance performance of recognizing text from the image of capcha using pytesseract OCR

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, captcha, python-tesseract

I need to extract text from these kinds of captcha images.
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W5Qr.png)
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Kvc.png)

my code is:

```
img = cv2.imread('abs2.png')

#convert into grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#removing noise
noi = cv2.medianBlur(gray,3)
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
pytesseract.image_to_string(noi, config=custom_config)
```

my output: [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOGOC.png) and [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGgRw.png).
Additionally, I also applied different approaches from [recognize text from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745519/use-pytesseract-ocr-to-recognize-text-from-an-image) and also try to apply some OpenCV related approaches but nothing seems to give me good results.

How can I improve the image to extract the string value or are there any other approaches to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: please accept my pardon if it is a beginner level post.