# how to improve pytesseract arguments to work properly

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I would like to read this captcha using pytesseract:

[image]

I follow the advice here: [Use pytesseract OCR to recognize text from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745519/use-pytesseract-ocr-to-recognize-text-from-an-image)

My code is:

```py
import pytesseract
import cv2

def captcha_to_string(picture):
    image = cv2.imread(picture)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # Morph open to remove noise and invert image
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
    invert = 255 - opening

    cv2.imwrite('thresh.jpg', thresh)
    cv2.imwrite('opening.jpg', opening)
    cv2.imwrite('invert.jpg', invert)

    # Perform text extraction
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, lang='eng', config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
    return text
```

But my code returns `8\n\x0c` which is nonsense.

This is how thresh looks like:

[image]
This is how opening looks like:

[image]
This is how invert looks like:

[image]

Can you help me, how can I improve `captcha_to_string` function to read the captcha properly? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right way. Removing the noise (small black spots in the inverted image) looks like the way to extract the text successfully.

FYI, the configuration of `pytessearct` makes the outcome worse only. So, I removed it.

My approach is as follows:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

def remove_noise(img,threshold):
    """
    remove salt-and-pepper noise in a binary image
    """
    filtered_img = np.zeros_like(img)
    labels,stats= cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img.astype(np.uint8),connectivity=8)[1:3]

    label_areas = stats[1:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]
    for i,label_area in enumerate(label_areas):
        if label_area > threshold:
            filtered_img[labels==i+1] = 1
    return filtered_img


def preprocess(img_path):
    """
    convert the grayscale captcha image to a clean binary image
    """
    img = cv2.imread(img_path,0)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3), 0)

    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

    filtered_img = 255-remove_noise(thresh,20)*255

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    erosion = cv2.erode(filtered_img,kernel,iterations = 1)
    return erosion

def extract_letters(img):
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)#,config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')

    return text


img = preprocess('captcha.jpg')

text=extract_letters(img)
print(text)

plt.imshow(img,'gray')
plt.show()
```

This is the processed image.

[image: binary captcha image]

And, the script returns `18L9R`.