# How to accurately detect slightly sloped text next to a bounding box/object?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

My objective is to extract text situated next to a detected bounding box (in my case the selected options), considering possible slopes either upwards or downwards in the text. The slopes may occur due to folding the document or the camera angle.

I have directly cropped the [original_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcf19.jpg) based on the bounding box (x,y,w,h). Then perform OCR on the cropped image to extract the text, which is perfect in almost all cases. But the text portion is also cropped in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj14M.png).

I need to detect the full text on question-7(C), expected output:

> Provides facilities for disk checking, error logging,

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

bbx=([[144, 1965, 47, 43]]) #list of bounding boxes
thresh = 255 - cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
for i in range(len(bbx)):
  x,y,w,h = bbx[i][:4]
  x,y,w,h = x+w+4,y,1000,h
  ROI = thresh[y:y+h,x:x+w]
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI, lang='eng',config='--oem 3 --psm 6')
  print(text)
  cv2.imshow(ROI)
```

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745519/use-pytesseract-ocr-to-recognize-text-from-an-image#:~:text=50-,Here%27s%20a%20simple,-approach %20using%20OpenCV reads the entire page quite accurately. You can then retrieve the data you need without cropping the image.

Comment: @СергейКох Thank you for reply. But how can I retrieve the text data from the exact portion following the bounding boxes?